# Determining sum of a series when given some information

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem:
The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ is a geometric series. It is known that $b_1 = 7$, and that $$\frac{b_{2023}}{b_{2022}} = \frac{1}{2}$$ Find the sum of the series.

What I've tried:
I rearranged to get $$b_{2023} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot b_{2022}$$
And considered the possibility that $$ b_n = \frac{1}{2}b_{n-1} \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = 7\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots\right) = 7\left(\frac{1}{1-0.5}\right) = 14 $$

But this is based on the assumption that $$b_n = \frac{1}{2}b_{n-1}$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Definition: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is a geometric series iff...

Comment: I think that's right, as a geometric series, the ratio between terms is common.

Comment: The *definition* of a geometric series is that, for all $n \ge 1$ it holds that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ has a constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is valid. In a geometric sequence, each term after the first is obtained by multiplying its predecessor by the ratio of the sequence. This means that $b_{n+1}/b_n = r$ for any $n = 1, 2, \ldots$. In particular, it is true for $n=2022$, so you have correctly determined that $r = \frac12$.